# I keep getting Exception on Tesseract Reading on my Program, but when I create a new program it works flawlessly

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Exception is Thrown to the Application I want OCR to be implemented but when I try to create new application with the same code it works flawlessly. I'm afraid of redoing all the work I did just for the Tesseract.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Open Image";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);

                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default);
            Page page = engine.Process(img, PageSegMode.Auto);
            string result = page.GetText();
            textBox1.Text = result;
        }
```

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(string, bool, int, bool) in path.cs
    System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(string) in path.cs
    InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.CheckExecutingAssemblyDomain(string, string)
    InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(string, string)
    InteropRuntimeImplementer.LeptonicaApiSignaturesInstance.LeptonicaApiSignaturesImplementation.LeptonicaApiSignaturesImplementation(InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader)
```

Keeps calling this Exception, I tried it on fresh Winforms and it works but its not working on the project that I have.

Comment: Having a similar issue. Mine occurs when I publish the executable, running in release or debug works fine. My call stack is:
`at System.IO.Path.Combine(String , String )`
`at InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.InternalLoadLibrary(String baseDirectory, String platformName, String fileName)`
`at InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.CheckExecutingAssemblyDomain(String fileName, String platformName)`
`at InteropDotNet.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(String fileName, String platformName)`
`at InteropRuntimeImplementer.LeptonicaApiSignaturesInstance.LeptonicaApiSignaturesImplementation..ctor(LibraryLoader loader)`

Answer (score 0):

I actually just created a new one, and redo everything and its working flawlessly. But if someone can still tell me what is wrong with the problem above, would be a big help.